# C++ substr method - "invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function"

Tags: c++, this, substr

I tried to compile the following code

```
std::string key = "DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=";
std::cout << "last five characters: " << key.substr(this.end()-5) << '\n';
```

And the compiler says

```
error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
std::cout << "last five characters: " << key.substr(this.end()-5) << '\n';
                                                   ^
```

`substr` is a "public member function" of `std::string`, why can't I use `this`?

I know I could just reference `key` again instead of `this`, but my original code was

```
std::cout << "Description: " << line.substr(found+key.length()+1).substr(this.begin(),this.length()-1) << '\n';
```

In the second use of `substr`, the string does not have a name, so the only way to refer to it would be `this`. I fixed it with

```
std::cout << "Description: " << line.substr(found+key.length()+1,line.length()-found-key.length()-2) << '\n';
```

But I am now curious to why `this` won't work.

Comment: On top of the whole `this` thing, `substr` takes indices, not iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is only available when you are writing code as part of a non-static method of a class. In your particular case, it seems obvious to you that `this` should refer to `key`, but the compiler sees no reason for that.

Also, string.substr() takes an integer indicating the beginning position.  string.end() returns an iterator, which will not work.  What you likely want to do here is call string.length().

Simply replace the first piece of code with:

```
std::cout << "last five characters: " << key.substr(key.length()-5) << '\n';
```

And you should be okay.